# Get a particular key value from json in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

```
[ 
"KEY1":{"SUB_KEY1" : "VALUE1","SUB_KEY2" : "VALUE2"},
"KEY2":{"SUB_KEY1" : "VALUE1","SUB_KEY2" : "VALUE2"}
]
```

The above is my json object which is coming as a response.

How do I get `SUB_KEY1` of `KEY1` and `SUB_KEY1` of `KEY2` in Ruby on Rails?

Thank you.

Comment: To be a valid JSON it either should be `{"K1": ..., "K2": ...}` or `[{"K1": ...}, {"K2": ...}]`. See [JSON definition](https://www.json.org/).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`parsed_json = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(your_json_string)`

will parse your string as

```
 [{"KEY1"=>{"SUB_KEY1"=>"VALUE1", "SUB_KEY2"=>"VALUE2"}}, {"KEY2"=>{"SUB_KEY1"=>"VALUE1", "SUB_KEY2"=>"VALUE2"}}]
```

You should be able to access it using something like  `parsed_json[1]["KEY2"]["SUB_KEY1"]`

Comment: Wouldn't it be the 0th index like `parsed_json[0]["KEY2"]["SUB_KEY1"]`?

Answer (score 51):

You need to parse the JSON object into a ruby hash. Assuming your JSON response is called res:

```
require 'json'
obj = JSON.parse(res)

sv1 = obj['KEY1']['SUB_KEY1']
```

etc.

Answer (score 1):

You need to parse JSON data first. Then loop over the JSON object to access the key as follow:

```
@response = JSON.parse(HTTParty.get(your_url).body)
@response["data"].each do |key|
  puts data[0][key]
  puts data[0][key2]
end
```