# Parsing Ruby JSON/hash to get single value

Tags: json, ruby, hash

I am very new to ruby and could not find any examples of what I wanted to do though I am sure there is many out there.

I have a ruby json object that I need to get a certain value out of the first key pair in it. Below is the ruby/json and I want to take that and get the `token` value from it.

`{"token"=>"<my token>", "dc"=>"test-dc"}`

How do I get the token?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get a particular key value from json in ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5348449/get-a-particular-key-value-from-json-in-ruby)

Comment: `=>` doesn't look like JSON, that looks like a Ruby hash. So, what exactly is your input? A string containing some JSON? Or a Ruby hash?

Comment: @MarcinKołodziej That link is useless to me, I have tried already and it didn't work. I get `uninitialized constant` for `ActiveSupport`

Comment: Wait, this isn't even JSON, this is a simple hash. This is so easily googlable, have you really tried to google a solution? It's `hash["token"]`.

Comment: @spickermann It is technically a hash but I figured they were the same thing as a json object in ruby since I have been able to use them in API calls where it required json

Comment: @MarcinKołodziej If I had found it on google I would not have posted here....

Comment: @JoshKirby No, a Ruby hash isn't the same as a JSON string. Perhaps you are runig a library that translates parameters automatically?

Comment: [This](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/Hash.html) is the first result in google after searching for "ruby hash value", [this](http://ruby-for-beginners.rubymonstas.org/built_in_classes/hashes.html) is the third one. Hashes are one of the most common data structures in Ruby and it does sound improbable that you have not been able to find an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ruby Hash objects and JSON "objects" might seem similar superficially but there's important differences.

Ruby's internal Hash looks like this when expressed with `inspect`:

```
{"token"=>"<my token>", "dc"=>"test-dc"}
```

Whereas JSON, which is a language-neutral data format inspired by JavaScript, looks like:

```
{"token": "<my token>", "dc": "test-dc"}
```

These are superficially similar, but the important difference is that if you have the former, not as a string but as a `Hash`, you can just use it:

```
hash["token"]
```

If you have the latter you'll need to parse it with something like `JSON.load`:

```
JSON.load('{"token": "<my token>", "dc": "test-dc"}')["token"]
```

Of course if you have Ruby and want JSON you can always dump it:

```
JSON.dump({"token"=>"<my token>", "dc"=>"test-dc"})
# => "{\"token\":\"<my token>\",\"dc\":\"test-dc\"}
```

Note that the arguments to `dump` are actual Ruby code and not a string like in the previous example. The output is a string, and as such, double-quotes need to be escaped with backslash. If you actually `print` this you'll see it without the extra escaping and it looks normal, that's just an artifact of how Ruby presents strings using `inspect`.