# How can I iterate a JSON object in a rails controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I'm passing the following data set to my controller in JSON format:

```
[
    {id: 0, exercises: [15, 18]},
    {id: 1, exercises: [33, 35]} 
]
```

This is received in my controller where I have to following code to display it temporarily:

```
arr = params["_json"]
binding.pry
```

This gives me the following output in the pry console:

```
[3] pry(#<ProgramsController>)> arr
=> [<ActionController::Parameters {"id"=>0, "exercises"=>[16, 7, 18]} permitted: false>,
<ActionController::Parameters {"id"=>1, "exercises"=>[14, 15]} permitted: false>]
```

I can then iterate this by going through arr[0] and arr[1], but how do I get the exercises that lie within these indexes?

So I can do something like this.

```
arr.each do |x|
  prog = Program.create(x ...)
  x.each do |exercise|
    prog.exercises.create(exercise_id: exercise.id)
  end
end
```

Hope someone can help me out handling this data. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get a particular key value from json in ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5348449/get-a-particular-key-value-from-json-in-ruby)

Comment: You need to parse it to a hash then modify the hash.

Answer (score 0):

Try using JSON.parse :)

```
arr = JSON.parse params["_json"]
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution was quite simply: arr[0]["exercises"]

No parsing needed, thanks tho :)

Comment: For the record: your initial code sample is not JSON, it's a Ruby hash. JSON has string keys, not symbols as in your example. A detail but it might help explain why you can reference it directly.

Answer (score 0):

To iterate over JSON in Rails. Try the following:

```
<ul>
arr.each do |a|
   <li><%= a[id] %></li>
   <li><%= a[exercises] %></li>
end
</ul>
```

OR

you can also try

```
@result = JSON.parse(HTTParty.get(your_url).body)
@result["arr"].each do |key, value|
  puts key
  puts value
end
```